# Test if a DOM element or JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose a function accepts one argument that is whether a DOM element or JSON that are wrapped in jQuery object or not, so how to tell one from the other?

Comment: FYI, what you call a JSON object is actually called a JavaScript object; JSON is merely a notation of a JS object (JavaScript Object Notation).

Comment: JSON must be plain text. Otherwise, it's no longer JSON :-?

Comment: @Álvaro – Indeed, and it must conform to [the spec](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 2):

you're probably looking for something like this:

```
var get_unknown_element = function(element) {
        var ele     = element,
            type    = Object.prototype.toString.call(ele);

        // string as passed in, we just assume it to be a jQuery (or querySelectorAll) selector string
        if(type === '[object String]') {                
            return (function(e){
               return e.length ? e : null; 
            }($(ele)));
        }
        // an object was passed in, if we have an jquery object & length > 0, just return it
        else if(type === '[object Object]' && ele.jquery && ele.length) {
            return ele;
        }    
        // native DOM object (node) was passed in, just call the jQuery constructor on it & return           
        else if(/^\[object HTML/.test(type)) {
            return $(ele);
        }
        // return null on no match
        else return null;                         
};
```